# Order by Join Table Attribute in Many-to-Many Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a many-to-many relation between Resumes and Educations which allows for the same education entry to appear on multiple resumes. When displaying Educations on a resume, I want the Educations to be ordered for that specific resume. To do this I set up a join table, Educations_Resumes, with the order information as a property.

However, when I try some like resume.educations I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "order": syntax error: 
SELECT "educations".* FROM "educations" INNER JOIN "educations_resumes" ON 
"educations"."id" = "educations_resumes"."education_id" WHERE 
"educations_resumes"."resume_id" = 2 ORDER BY educations_resumes.order
```

The models are setup as:

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :educations_resumes
  has_many :educations, :through => :educations_resumes,
           :order => 'educations_resumes.order'

end

class EducationsResume < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resume
  belongs_to :education
end

class Education < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :educations_resumes
  has_many :resumes, :through => :educations_resumes
end
```

Any suggestions on how to correctly order resume.educations would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a keyword as a column name:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Run a migration and change the column name:

```
rails g migration FixColumnName
```

This will give you a empty migration file that you should fill in with something like:

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :educations_resumes, :order, :ordering
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I overlooked something like that.

Comment: No problem, i am really glad i could help you, and sorry for some slippery answers at first, i must learn to read better, but the fact that you named the column `order` kinda threw me out of track when i saw your code :) Good luck!